# How to use addCls() in extjs 3.2

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I am try to delete row from a grid. For that I need to strike a row. I am using addCls but it is not supporting in extjs 3. What is the alternate way to do that.

```
{ 
xtype: 'button', 
text: 'Delete',
handler : function(){
    var cogrid = Ext.getCmp('HART_GRID');
    var costore = cohartgrid.getStore();
    var record = Ext.getCmp('HART_GRID').getSelectionModel().getSelected();
    if (record) {
        Ext.fly(row).addCls('row-deleted');// This line is throwing error.
    }
    if(record.data.Excl == "No"){
        cohartstore.remove(record);
    }
} }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ExtJS you can not use `addCls` but what you can use is `addClass`

As per your code you need index of `row`and then use

`Ext.fly(row[i]).addClass('row-deleted');`