# How to strike a perticular row in extjs on click of button

Tags: css, extjs, extjs3

I have a grid with row. I want to give a strike on click of particular button. Here is my code.

```
{ 
xtype: 'button', 
text: 'Exclude',
handler : function(){
    debugger;
    var cohartgrid = Ext.getCmp('abc');
    var cohartstore = cohartgrid.getStore();
    var record = Ext.getCmp('abc').getSelectionModel().getSelected();
    var st = cohartstore.getRange();
     if (record) {
        Ext.fly(row).addCls('row-deleted');// This line is not working. 
    }

    if(record.data.EXL == "No"){
       record.set("EXL","YES")
    }
}}
```

What css I have to put. Thanks for help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use addCls() in extjs 3.2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38156553/how-to-use-addcls-in-extjs-3-2)

Comment: Here I want to know how to strike a row with css or js. I paste code to show what I have done so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered same kind of question in other post. Here you need to get the index of your row and then place strike css by using `addClass`. remember extjs 3 is not supporting addCls

```
     var selection = grid.getSelectionModel();
     for(var i=0;i<gridstore.data.length;i++){
      if(selection.isSelected(i)){
      var test = grid.getView().getRow(i);
      var dsd=Ext.fly(test);
      dsd.addClass('StrikeCSS'); // Placing css to that perticular row.
        }
  }
```

In answer grid is your grid. In selection you getting row index and placing Strike

```
.StrikeCSS {
  text-decoration: line-through !important;
   color : BLACK !important;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use code to add class in selected row :

```
rowIndex = cohartgrid.getStore().indexOf(selectedRecord);
cohartgrid.getView().addRowCls(rowIndex, 'row-deleted');
```

Comment: Is addRowCls function I need to define anywhere. ?  I am getting `VM46518:1 Uncaught TypeError: cohartgrid.addRowCls is not a function(…) error. `

Comment: I think grid don't have any direct method to add row class. So first you have to find the view of grid then add row on that.

cohartgrid.getView().addRowCls(rowIndex, 'row-deleted');